# What is a meromorphic connection?

Tags: complex-geometry

Given a positive holomorphic line bundle, what is the meromorphic (flat) connection? Is it a connection in the form of $d+\sum \frac{A}{z-z_0}+$holomorphic function, what is the order of the pole? Any textbook I can find such definition?

Answer (score 3):

A meromorphic connection is a meromorphic section of the bundle whose local sections are local connections, sometimes called the connection bundle. In a local trivialization, a meromorphic connection becomes a connection with meromorphic connection 1-form. I am not sure of the best reference, but a standard work that uses meromorphic connections is P. Deligne, Equations différentielles à points singuliers réguliers. Lect. Notes Math. 163, 1970.